# Is there a way to read JS code as part of a JS file from another JS file ? (The app uses NodeJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working on a web app using **NodeJS**. The concept is : the main structure, to which you add the tools you want depending on what you want in your app.

To achieve that, I want my main JS file (*index.js*) to read the content of another file (*tool.js*) as if it was part of the code.

I know I can require a module in NodeJS and call a function from it, but this isn't what I want as I don't want to put the content of the file in a function. Here is an example of what I would like to achieve :

tool.js :

```
// tool.js
// This executes various actions.
var web_func = require(web_funcs.js); // another module, not important

web_func.executeAction();
console.log('whatever');
```

index.js :

```
// index.js
// This is the main file

/*Here I want to call tool.js*/
```

The goal is to have index.js be read as this :

```
// index.js
// This is the main file

// tool.js
// This executes various actions.
var web_func = require(web_funcs.js); // another module, not important

web_func.executeAction();
console.log('whatever');
```

The reason behind this is that I want my mainframe to be easy to deploy with minimal adjustments, and everything regarding the tools to be handled in a different file to make it easier to read.

And since there are several tools and the number will probably grow, I want it to be easily set-up.

If you have any idea or solution, please let me know, as it would be of great help. I've tried looking around but didn't find anything.

EDIT : changed the title of the question for better clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the file first and then use the `eval()` method to execute the code in string.

Read the code and call eval using this sample:

**my-file.js**

```
var a = "test";
console.log(a);
```

**Code:**

```
var fs = require('fs');
var code = fs.readFileSync('my-file.js', 'utf8');
eval(code);
```

**Output:**

```
test
```

**Edit 1:**

You can also reuse the variables from the other file in this way. For example, add `console.log(a)` after the `eval(code)` line.

```
...
eval(code);
console.log(a);
```

The output will be:

```
test
test
```

Comment: Thank you ! This was indeed what I was looking for. I don't understand why I did not find it earlier, I probably didn't look in the right place.